# How I can create a profile for each user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with firebase, and I have a problem I need that a new user is added into my profile table when their are the first time login.

I can't find the way for login with social media, and for login with email, what I do is push a new register with the uid to the table when the  user is in the register form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Use the [Trigger on user creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) :

```
exports.saveUserInDatabase = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data; // The Firebase user

    const id = user.uid; // The id of the user
    const email = user.email; // The email of the user
    const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user

    // Add user in the database
    return admin.database().ref('/users').child(id).child('userData').set('userValue');
});
```

[You can find here some firebase cloud functions samples.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

Comment: Thank you help me a lot, with this.